# Save data efficiently to sql table(s)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, business-intelligence, bids

Every 15 minutes we read and parse an XML file that includes kpi scores of one **element**. This element has 5 **sub-elements** and each sub-element has **400 kpi scores**. There are around **250 elements** (250 files), which means that every 15 minutes I'll be storing 500K kpi scores **(250 elements * 5 sub-elements * 400 kpi scores = 500K KPIs)**

This data will be used for reporting, mostly aggregating all this data hourly and daily. In other words, most of the KPIs will eventually be grouped. But the first step is to somehow store the individual counters.

The first, most common, thought was to create a table with the columns being the KPIs. But this was done with similar data, and performance was sub-par, to say the least.

So my question is, what would be the best way to store this raw data?

I was considering of creating a small table that would include the following columns: [Date], [Hour], [Minute], [KPI], [Score]. The problem here (I think) will be the difficulty of querying the data; with a "regular" table, I can simply SELECT KPI1, KPI2, KPI29 from TABLE GROUP BY *whatever*. With this new format, grouping several KPIS with just one query would be slightly more difficult.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the raw data as such then the best way is store it on a column type XML within a table (plus date/time and maybe other data to identify the load)

Comment: Thanks. By "raw data" I meant all the actual counters. We already save a copy of the XML File.

Answer (score 0):

@Jayvee is completely correct (+1).  I would add: querying raw data is usually slow.  Store aggregates as soon as possible and query the aggregates instead of the raw data.  The raw data should usually only get used/queried for historical and diagnostic purposes.

What I mean by "store aggregates as soon as possible": you could calculate them on import (maybe slowing your import), or (better) you could (also) insert them into a (2nd) "buffer" table and run a separate job to aggregate the buffered records and then clear the buffer.  That way, you don't have to query the massive history table to aggregate your new data.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the data will be only used for historical purposes, but I still have to store it. Regardless, in order to group the hourly data, I need to wait an hour, which means I would need to store the 4 files (1 every 15-mins) and then do the grouping.